# What user does classic asp run as?

Tags: asp-classic

I have an asp page that saves a file to disk.

Currently it works locally, but I need to save the file to a share and I get permission denied.

I had assumed I could just set the app pool to the user that has access to the folder, but it doesn't seem to work.

How do you make classic asp run as a specific user?

Comment: IIS 6 or 7?  Intranet solution or a public web site?

Comment: Just for my own reference when I end up back here in a year's time, my default installation of IIS 10 was using the account 'IUSR' (no machinename) for Classic ASP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that by default classic asp will run under the iis user which is IUSR_MachineName.  This can be changed in the IIS Manager.

Good references:

- http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/153/tn_15378.html
- http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=287

Answer (score 1):

IIS Admin - Website Properties - Directory Security - Edit...

By default it's IUSR_MACHINENAME

Comment: so are you saying enable anonymous access and then change the user?
if so I tried that and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Seems like it was caching credentials or something because after reseting iis and closing all browsers/exporer windows it started working :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at who is running the following:

- "inetinfo.exe" process
- "World Wide Web Publishing service"

It should be one of those I believe.

Comment: inetinfo.exe is running as system
World Wide Web Publsihing Service is running as the system account.
I can't change either of those as they are for the whole server.

the w3wp.exe is running as my user (that has access to the share)

Comment: The worker process is for ASP.Net applications, not classic ASP.  Could you change it into ASP.Net instead?

Comment: yeah I realise that, was hoping that classic asp would pick up those permissions as well.
can't rewrite in this case unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible to put the ASP on the same machine where the share is?  I realize this may be a trivial solution but it just an idea I had.

Comment: no, the share is on a SAN and the servers are load balanced :)

Comment: Darn, back to the drawing board then I guess. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is the program attempting to go to a share on another computer (or this computer), or a folder on the web server which happens to also be a share?  When you access it through the `\\server\share` notation, you are going to have different issues than through the local drive `driveletter:\folder\` notation.

If it is a share on another computer, the account will need to have rights to the share as well as rights to the underlying files and must be a domain account.

Comment: it is a share on another computer (actually a SAN).
I am using \\computer\sharename with the old file system object. does this not work?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are actually doing but you would probably want to avoid giving the whole application a user identity that has network access just to service the needs of this one file.

You can configure in IIS the user identity for anonymous access on that one ASP file, that would be better than setting it for the whole application.

Another option in the intranet environment is to turn off anonymous access for the ASP file and turn on windows integrated access.  The clients user account is used for the security context for running the ASP and any subsequent network access it might make.

Comment: how do you run a specific asp file as a particular identity?
I can't change the way security works too much as that would blow our budget.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem : Unable to Execute Bat EXE or CMD.exe from classic ASP pages on IIS 7.

As **I have found a solution**, I HOPE it will help the folks to save time !

**For a solution look there** : (I've Marked the very last post as Answer).

[http://forums.iis.net/t/1193937.aspx/1?+BAT+and+vbs+Files+does+not+run+anymore+from+Classic+ASP+was+running+on+Win+2003+Server+](http://forums.iis.net/t/1193937.aspx/1?%20BAT%20and%20vbs%20Files%20does%20not%20run%20anymore%20from%20Classic%20ASP%20was%20running%20on%20Win%202003%20Server%20)

Have a great starting 2013 !