# Can't run command line in ASP classic

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have a problem on my windows 2003 server under IIS6. I can't launch a command line with Wscript.Shell. Here is a part of my code:

```
Set WshShell = Server.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
WshShell.Run "cd "C:\Program Files\WinRAR" && WinRAR.exe a -afzip "D:\www\cpamodule\File\GED\UPLOADS\438\5\104192\DocZipped.zip" "D:\www\cpamodule\File\GED\UPLOADS\438\5\104192\123650.pdf"
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug ASP permission problems with WScript.Shell object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/897412)

Comment: Check the identity used by the Application Pool. Does the ASP script have `Execute` permission? Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132237/692942) may be relevant.

Comment: Where can I check the identity used by the application pool ?

Comment: In IIS Manager, go to the Application Pools select the pool in the list and view the advanced settings to see the ApplicationPoolIdentity being used.